# Resizing images in a gallery to fit the rows but keeping the aspect ratio of each image

Tags: jquery, css, image, resize, image-gallery

I need to display a gallery of images that are roughly of similar size but not exactly equal and their aspect ratios are also different.

I would like to display them in rows of variable height but the all row having the same total width fitting the screen size. Each image is allowed to scale (ideally as little as possible) preserving aspect ratio to fit the height of its row.

Is there a simple way to do it or perhaps a library (or jQuery plugin or AngularJS directive)?

I have checked several libraries imitating Pinterest design, which however make fixed column width instead of fixed row width. That is great for infinite scroll but is not suitable for showing a small gallery of fixed size (5-50 images).

Comment: just use css to set the width you want (eg `img { width:100px; }`), don't put in a value for the height and then they will resize keeping there ratio

Comment: You want something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/yRUXQ/1/) ? PS: some images are big, done it quickly so you may wait a while for them to load :)

Comment: @Pete thanks, I can do it with height but still need to calculate it. Do you perhaps know a library doing this?

Comment: @BatuZet Not quite - here missing space is filled by a background, but the actual image heights are different. I need to scale them instead to have the same height for each row.

Comment: So rows are gonna be scaled too. Because if row size ratio (w/h) is lower then image ratio and if you set the image height to row height then image is going to overflow. So row width needs to be reset according to this overflowing image. Is that right?

Comment: @BatuZet Yes, if the image row overflows, the whole row should be scaled back to fit the element width. This seems to be the most natural solution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is one plugin I have developed. So far a jQuery plugin, but an AngularJS version will come soon. It is called **[jPictura](https://github.com/anmarcek/jpictura)**.

See a **[working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2zcxp6u/4/)**. I believe it does exactly what you need and its usage is as simple as this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my-gallery').jpictura({
        layout: { itemSpacing: 0, justifyLastRow: true, idealRowHeight: 200}
    });
});

<div id="my-gallery">
    <div class="item"><img src="foo.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="bar.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

See the full documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/anmarcek/jpictura).